# Using an Elastic Load Balancer for SSH traffic

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, phabricator

I am wanting to setup an AWS Elastic Load Balancer in front of a Phabricator installation. I would like the ELB to balance HTTP, HTTPS and SSH traffic. Is this possible or do I need to run my own SSH load balancer with HAProxy or similar?

To clarify, I am aiming to load balance git operations which occur over SSH, as distinct from administrative SSH.

Comment: Have you had any luck with this?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Answer (score -2):

In my case of Phabricator + AWS ELB setup

1. Allowed ELB port for phab instances.
2. Configured VirtualHost redirection from HTTP to HTTPS in apache sites-enable configuration file. First rules all HTTPS connection forwarded to "[https://phab.example.com/index.php?**path**=](https://phab.example.com/index.php?__path__=)$1" and the second rule is catching HTTP connection and redirects to HTTPS.

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>   :
>   ...
>     RewriteEngine On
>     RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =https
>     RewriteRule ^(.*)$          /index.php?__path__=$1  [B,L,QSA]
>     RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
>     RewriteRule . https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]  
>   ...
>  :    
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

3. Change Phabricator base url to HTTPS with port(443) in phab configuration (local.json)

I hope this will Help you

Comment: This has nothing to do with load balancing SSH traffic.