# Redirecting from Http to Https with AWS's ELB

Tags: .htaccess, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redirect, amazon-elb

I have made queries before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43713304/redirecting-from-http-to-https-with-awss-elb-in-chrome-and-firefox). I considered it was working, but actually not yet.

I have load balancer facing to Internet and behind is Ec2 instance.
My load balancer is opened to port 80 and port 443.

They are arranged as 80 -> 80 and 443 -> 80.

Now is I need to redirect http access to https.

What I did is 
I made a .htaccess file and located into /var/www/html/. That is the folder where my website's index.php is located.

Inside .htaccess file, I tried a few version what I found in the Internet. None of them worked.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^ELB-HealthChecker
    RewriteRule . https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.(.+) [OR,NC]    # Added
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://domainname.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

Why it doesn't work at my set up?

EDIT:

```
<If "req('X-Forwarded-Proto') != 'https'>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^ELB-HealthChecker
    RewriteRule . https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]
</If>
```

Comment: I got a reply from AWS for a clue is that ELB just insert the redirection info using X-Forwarded-Proto. So actual implementation of redirection needs to be happened in the instance, in the apache. I need to figure out how.

Comment: Similar problem solved for Phabricator. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48149369/7098257

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been solving the issue for a long time and now can make it work successfully. I like to share what I have done as follows.

```
(1)Create .htaccess file inside the folder same as root file index.php exists
(2).htaccess file has
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule . https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]
(3)Then enable mod_rewrite, try the command line command: 
   sudo a2enmod rewrite
(4)To make sure mod_rewrite is enabled, update /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file as
<Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
initially is 
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

Then you can setup http to https successfully
You need to restart server as sudo service apache2 restart after update of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Your load balancer and its security group need to open to http access.

Answer (score 0):

What I do for HTTPS with apache is upload a custom `redirect.conf` file via [container commands](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands). So `redirect.conf` looks something like this:

```
<If "req('X-Forwarded-Proto') != 'https'>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule . https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
</If>
```

And then you'd use a container command to put this file into the apache configuration directory `/etc/httpd/conf.d/` like so:

```
container_commands:
  01_update_rewrite_rules:
    command: "cp rewrite.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d/"
```

Comment: do you mean to put this inside /etc/httpd folder and inside has conf.d file. I can't find /etc/httpd folder. Same to conf.d also

Comment: which AMI are you using? `/etc/httpd/conf.d/` is the default apache configuration directory on linux

Comment: I use Ubuntu 16.06

Comment: gotcha, just to be clear this will be on your ec2 instance, not on your personal machine (unless you have apache on it too).

Comment: check `/etc/apache2/` it should have a subdirectory called `conf.d`. that's where you'll want to put your custom config files

Comment: These are all file inside /etc/apache2. apache2.conf    conf-available  envvars  mods-available  ports.conf      sites-enabled
apache2.conf.save  conf-enabled    magic    mods-enabled    sites-available. Do you mean apache2.conf

Comment: yep that's the one then, i use centos on ec2 so i guess the configuration directory is in a different place for debian-based linux. Anyway, you can upload arbitrary configuration files into that directory and then reload apache. If you do this via container commands the reload is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks let me try

Comment: I put redirect.conf inside /etc/apache2 folder, that is where apache2.conf is located. but still doesn't work. redirect.conf is shown in EDIT in the original post.

Comment: I got a reply from AWS for a clue is that ELB just insert the redirection info using X-Forwarded-Proto. So actual implementation of redirection needs to be happened in the instance, in the apache. I need to figure out how.